# Trouble getting domain name associated with AWS to point to Heroku app

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku

I am following Heroku's instructions on how to get my AWS domain name on Route 53 to point to my Heroku app. The end of the instructions say:

"Go back to the Hosted Zones list and select your new hosted zone. There is a pre-populated Delegation Set section in the sidebar. These are the nameservers you need to provide your domain registrar for Route 53 to resolve your app domain."

I assume that the nameservers they are referring to are the four web addresses with "awsdns" in their name with type NS. My question is, who is my domain registrar and how do I provide these name servers to them? I originally bought this domain through GoDaddy before transferring it to AWS. Is GoDaddy my domain registrar? How do I determine this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you transfer the domain to AWS, or did you simply create a hosted zone for the domain name? If you transferred the domain to AWS, which it doesn't sound like you did, the nameservers are configured by Route 53 and are set. It sounds like you need to go to the Domain Settings via the GoDaddy console and set the AWS nameservers as your nameservers for your GoDaddy domain.